# rewrite $2ie^{i\pi}+i^3$

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, problem-solving

i am asked to rewrite $2ie^{i\pi}+i^3$ into $x+iy$ form. i just tried all what i know so far, but couldnot come to solution. i said: $2ie^{i\pi}+i^3=2ie^{i\pi}-i$ but further i am stuck really. i am really eager to learn how things like this work. i appreciate any help and attempt to help.

the more difficult problems i am facing, the more i am loving maths. this problem was the first problem in my exam today. it took me 20 minutes. no sign of success..

EDIT: sorry, i forgot $e$. now it is there

Comment: Use $i = e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}}$ to expand the powers of $i$, and then use Euler's formula.

Comment: @copper.hat, how can this be? can you please explain me with small proof? btw, i forgot $e$ in my question, now updated

Comment: There is the famous equation $e^{\pi i}+1=0$

Comment: Are you familiar with $e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$?

Comment: @copper.hat, oh yeah. now i see what you mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the main branch for the logarithmic function

$$i^{\pi i}=e^{\pi i\operatorname{Log}(i)}=e^{\pi i\left(\log|i|+\frac{\pi i}{2}\right)}=e^{\pi i\frac{\pi i}{2}}=e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{2}}\Longrightarrow$$

$$2i^{\pi i}+i^3=2e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{2}}-i$$

**Added:** after a modification of the question by the OP (*much* simpler now):

$$2ie^{\pi i}+i^3=-2i-i=-3i$$

Comment: Thanks, but i forgot $e$ then updated my question, can you please update your answer also?

Answer (score 2):

Use Euler's formula:

$$e^{ix} = cos(x) + i sin(x)$$.

Plug in $x = \pi$ and you could then move on.

Answer (score 2):

$$2ie^{i\pi}+i^3$$
Recall that:
$$e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$$
Thus, $e^{i\pi} = -1$.  Substituting:
$$-2i+i^3$$
Continuing using basic properties of $i$:
$$-2i-i$$
$$\boxed{-3i}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ 2ie^{i\pi} + i^3 $$
$$ 2ie^{i\pi} - i $$

Recall Euler's Identity:

$$ e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$$
and so:
$$ e^{i\pi} = -1 $$
$$ 2i \cdot -1 - i$$
$$ -2i - i $$
$$ \color{red}{-3i} $$

---

Alternatively, use Euler's Formula, that:
$$ e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x $$
Using $x=\pi$:
$$ e^{i\pi} = \cos \pi + i \sin \pi $$
$$ e^{i\pi} = -1 + 0i $$
$$ e^{i\pi} = -1 $$

And proceed as above.

Comment: Georg, very nice. thanks in tons dude.